# could not authenticate OAuth while using twitter from sharekit in iphone app

Tags: iphone, twitter, sharekit

I m implementing facebook & twitter share using sharekit in iphone app. Facebook share is working fine but twitter share gives error "could not authenticate OAuth".

Answer (score 14):

I was having the same problem - this fixed it:

https://github.com/ideashower/ShareKit/issues/229

Summary:

Change SHKTwitter.m in lines 54-56 from

```
https://twitter.com/
```

to

```
https://api.twitter.com/
```

like this:

```
self.authorizeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"];
self.requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"];
self.accessURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"];
```

and in line 323, from http to https:

```
OAMutableURLRequest *oRequest = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json"]
consumer:consumer
token:accessToken
realm:nil
signatureProvider:nil];`
```

Comment: Hi Jephers, Thanks. hi all , line 323 is VERY important. I overlooked it, and that was one whole day wasted on debugging the problem. Just an "s"...

Comment: Please note that it's smart to call [SHKTwitter logout] as well since you will get login errors when switching (if you are switching from xauth to oauth that is)