# could not authenticate OAuth while using twitter from sharekit in iphone app

Tags: iphone, twitter, sharekit

could not authenticate OAuth while using twitter from sharekit in iphone app
I did all this

1. 'Application Type' should be set to BROWSER (not client)
2. 'Callback URL' should match whatever you enter in SHKTwitterCallbackUrl.  The callback url doesn't have to be an actual existing url.  The user will never get to it because ShareKit intercepts it before the user is redirected.  It just needs to match.

Comment: possible duplicate of [could not authenticate OAuth while using twitter from sharekit in iphone app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731394/could-not-authenticate-oauth-while-using-twitter-from-sharekit-in-iphone-app)

Answer (score 3):

Twitter updated their api, and seemingly the official repo wasn't updated (yet?). Take a look [here](http://jayrparro.posterous.com/incorrect-signature-sharekittwitter-error) on how to fix this.